# C++ Operator[] Overloading SNAFU

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, constants

I have a class that I would like to define the [] operator for.  The class holds a serial packet (along with the associated functions to operate on said packet).  I would like to have the user have the ability to do something like this...

```
MyClass packet;
uint8_t byte = packet[3];  // get third byte of packet
```

I would like to prevent the user from doing this...

```
packet[3] = 0xAA;  // this breaks encapsulation for my class :(
```

I have been looking around for a solution, and I was wondering if this declaration would be all that I needed (along with the associated code in my .cpp):

```
const uint8_t operator[](const std::size_t index) const;
```

Although I'm fairly certain that this will work, I still have some uncertainties about my approach, and I was hoping that ya'll could help me through my problems.

1. Is it "ok" to simply return the value, and not a reference?  I know that in ALL the examples I've seen a reference is returned.  Does returning a value help me get around the fact that I don't want the "[]" used on the left hand side of the operation?  Then again, doesn't the const prevent this?
2. Will the const function be called even on non-const object?  I've seen a few examples where there are a const version of the operator and a non-const of the operator declared.  The non-const allows for writing, whereas the const only allows reading, but is only called for const objects.  My goal here is to have even non-const objects only have the ability to be read from.
3. Is there a clean way to pass errors from the operator?  My main issue is that the data being requested may be outside the bounds of the data that I have.  All of the examples I've seen use an assert, but I don't necessarily want the program to crash in the event that the user's call to the operator causes some sort of hilarity.  I also can't necessarily pass back a special code since any value of the byte I'm passing back may be valid.

As always, thanks for your help as I slowly (but surely) make the scary transition from being a C programmer to a OO C++ wizard.

Comment: Do you really have a requirement that your code must not compile on a system where char is larger than 8 bits? Because that's what `uint8_t` does: it doesn't exist unless the system has an unsigned type with **exactly** 8 bits. Surely `uint_least8_t` or `uint_fast8_t` is more appropriate. Or even better, `unsigned char`, which will always be at least 8 bits.

Comment: I'm using uint_8t since this is the preferred method per Google's style guide http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#Integer_Types .  Also, the packet class will never, ever be run on a system where I can't get an unsigned type of exactly 8 bits.

Comment: Google's style guide has a reputation for often being misguided. It certainly is here, since it unnecessarily makes code non-portable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Yes, it is OK to simply return a value, for such a small type as `uint8_t`. You can return a const reference and `const` will indeed prevent anyone from writing through it. But with small types like `uint8_t` returning by value is a better idea. Note, BTW, that when returning by value you no longer need `const` on the return type.

   Returning a const reference, even tough it prevents modification, gives the calling code the ability to create and store potentially long-lived references and pointers to your array elements, as in

   ```
   const uint8_t *byte = &packet[3];
   ```

   If this is undesirable, then returning by value blocks that capability as well.
2. Yes, `const` version of the function will be called for non-const objects (assuming you haven't provided a non-const version).
3. Exceptions were introduced specifically for that purpose. Exceptions give you a dedicated feedback path for erroneous situations without affecting function declaration and specification (i.e. you don't have to reserve any values for error returns and don't have to introduce any parameters for that purpose).

Answer (score 1):

If you return by *value* and use

```
 packet[3] = 0xAA;
```

The compiler gives you an error since packet[3] is not a modifiable l-value, which means it cannot appear on the left-hand side of an assignment.

If you return by reference, then the user is able to edit whatever is referenced. You can use *const* reference to disallow modifications.

The reference approach has the advantage that you avoid a copy of the value, which can increase efficiency/space if the return value of operator[] is large. If you only want one copy to exist of the return value of operator[], then you must use a (const) reference.